# Webpack with CherryPy?

Tags: webpack, cherrypy

I have joined a new project, built on CherryPy and jinja2.   I would like to start using a css-preprocessor, and also need something to create SVG sprites for me.  Seeing as a bit down the line, we are going to be rewriting in React, I think it would make sense to use webpack.  Is it possible to use this with CherryPy, and if so, how would I go about integrating?  Many thanks in advance for any insights anyone can give me on this!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CherryPi Documentation on Static Assets](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-6-what-about-my-javascripts-css-and-images), it appears that you will need to configure a static location for your assets to go.

In terms of Webpack implementation:
Webpack is agnostic to your server side stack and simply requires a node environment to run your configuration.

Your 'publicPath' in your Webpack output config will represent that of the static asset path.

I would refer to [SurviveJS's posts on how to setup and understand how Webpack works. Plus it's example is a React Webpack example.](http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/webpack/)